# start Sphinx Confluence Builder multiply times

Tags: python, python-sphinx

i use [Sphinx Confluence Builder](https://sphinxcontrib-confluencebuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and i needed start it multiply times with different config in `config.py`, part of this file is:

```
branchs = ['branch1', 'branch2']

extensions = ['sphinxcontrib.confluencebuilder']
confluence_publish = True
confluence_space_name = 'TEST'
for branch in branchs:
    confluence_parent_page = 'Documentation: %s' % branch
confluence_server_url = 'https://intranet-wiki.example.com'
confluence_server_user = 'username'
confluence_server_pass = 'password'
confluence_lang_transform = lambda lang: 'python'
```

i start it by `python -m sphinx -b confluence . _build/confluence` command but builder was publishing only last of `branchs`.
Now it looking like:

```
-Documentation: branch1  
-Documentation: branch2
--page1
--page2
--page3
```

but expected:

```
-Documentation: branch1 
--page1
--page2
--page3 
-Documentation: branch2
--page1
--page2
--page3
```

drop-down pages `page1`, `page2`, `page3` under `Documentation branchX` are same

Answer (score 0):

Confluence does not support the ability to publish more than one page in a target space with the same name. What appears to be happening is that when `branch1` is processed, the expected content is published; however, when processing `branch2`, pages are being updated and moved under the new parent (`Documentation: branch2`).

To workaround this limitation, the configuration option [`confluence_publish_prefix`](http://sphinxcontrib-confluencebuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#confluence-publish-prefix) can be used to ensure both documentation sets are not conflicting. For example, with the following configuration:

```
confluence_publish_prefix = '{}-'.format(branch)
```

The published output should be:

```
-Documentation: branch1 
--branch1-page1
--branch1-page2
--branch1-page3 
-Documentation: branch2
--branch2-page1
--branch2-page2
--branch2-page3
```

*Disclosure: I am a collaborator for the Atlassian Confluence Builder for Sphinx extension.*